# Capture KeyEvent on RecyclerView Views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-keypad

Following the directions on [this](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/tracking-selected-item-in-recyclerview/) blog post I am able to track the selected item on a vertical list Adapter, but I cannot click or long click any item by pressing some key.

I've created this method

```
public static boolean isConfirmButton(KeyEvent event){
    switch (event.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

to intercept "confirm" buttons, but where's the right place to listen for `KeyEvents`? How to make a distinction between click and longclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the code from the post, by adding regular and long button presses:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;

    // Handle key up and key down and attempt to move selection
    recyclerView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            // Return false if scrolled to the bounds and allow focus to move off the list
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                    return tryMoveSelection(lm, 1);
                } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                    return tryMoveSelection(lm, -1);
                } else if(KeyEventUtils.isConfirmButton(event)){
                    View view = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mSelectedItem).itemView;
                    if((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS)==KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) {
                        view.performLongClick();
                    }
                    else{
                        view.performClick();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Now it works properly, I don't know if it's the most elegant way.