# Adding proper keyboard support to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-keypad

In one of my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921705/capture-keyevent-on-recyclerview-views), I asked (and answered by myself following [this](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/tracking-selected-item-in-recyclerview) blog post) how to properly handle key input on a `RecyclerView`.

Now I realized that if I keep an arrow key pressed, let's say down key, the scrolling downwards stops and the `RecyclerView` loses its focus, probably because the scrolling is faster than the generation of all the children `View`s.

Is there any workaround or better practice to properly handle hardware keyboard inputs on a `RecyclerView`?

**Update:**

I published a basic example [here](https://github.com/zevektor/KeyboardRecyclerView), it works flawlessly now, no more focus losses.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]? I was just adding keyboard support to a `RecyclerView` yesterday, along the lines of how you were doing it. In my case, it's a full-screen `RecyclerView`, so I didn't have any focus issues. It will be easier for people to help you get past a problem if we have a concrete implementation of the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll create my example asap. I think you might try adding a focusable view (e.g. a button) below your RecyclerView and use a large dataset in the adapter of, let's say, 100 items. You should see the focus behaving weirdly.

Comment: I will poke at this more tomorrow. I was seeing other odd results (e.g., smearing effect). I think perhaps we need to wait to update the `RecyclerView` a second time until after the first one is done processing, rather than one per key event. All that being said, having a focusable view below a vertically-scrolling list is not a good keyboard UX in the first place. You will see discussion about that sort of thing in coverage of writing apps for Android TV (or its Google TV predecessor, Fire TV, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare I might have solved the issue by myself, I started coding from scratch and I got this working example https://github.com/zevektor/KeyboardRecyclerView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to implement an abstract Adapter class capable of keeping track of the selected item without losing item focus, a sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/zevektor/KeyboardRecyclerView), the specific implementation of the adapter class is below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;


/**
 * Created by vektor on 31/05/16.
 */
public abstract class InputTrackingRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>{

    private Context mContext;
    private int mSelectedItem = 0;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public InputTrackingRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        // Handle key up and key down and attempt to move selection
        recyclerView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                // Return false if scrolled to the bounds and allow focus to move off the list
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (isConfirmButton(event)) {
                        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) {
                            mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mSelectedItem).itemView.performLongClick();
                        } else {
                            event.startTracking();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                            return tryMoveSelection(lm, 1);
                        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                            return tryMoveSelection(lm, -1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && isConfirmButton(event)
                        && ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) != KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS)){
                    mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mSelectedItem).itemView.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean tryMoveSelection(RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm, int direction) {
        int nextSelectItem = mSelectedItem + direction;

        // If still within valid bounds, move the selection, notify to redraw, and scroll
        if (nextSelectItem >= 0 && nextSelectItem < getItemCount()) {
            notifyItemChanged(mSelectedItem);
            mSelectedItem = nextSelectItem;
            notifyItemChanged(mSelectedItem);
            //lm.scrollToPosition(mSelectedItem);
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mSelectedItem);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Context getContext(){ return mContext; }

    public int getSelectedItem() { return mSelectedItem; }
    public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) { mSelectedItem = selectedItem; }

    public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() { return mRecyclerView; }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }

    public static boolean isConfirmButton(KeyEvent event){
        switch (event.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }


}
```